# OpenCV - Thinning with lines on binary mat leads to random horizontal dotted lines

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am writing a method to thin white lines from a binary image (the background is black). Essentially, the code loops through the image and finds consecutive white pixels that are in the same row, turns all of them black, and finally turns the pixel in the middle white. This algorithm works fairly well to thin the lines but produces random horizontal dotted lines where there shouldn't be anything at all. Below is an example:

Image to thin lines from:
[image]

Image after algorithm runs:
[image]

Clearly, the dotted lines near the top and bottom of the image shouldn't be there as there is no white areas there in the original image, yet somehow they are generated. I have attached my code to do the thinning below, and any help is greatly appreciated!

```
//Line thining
    double[] rgbCanny;
    int inARow = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < noiseReducedCanny.size().height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < noiseReducedCanny.size().width; j++) {

            rgbCanny = noiseReducedCanny.get(i, j);

            if(rgbCanny[0] == 255) {
                inARow++;
            } else {
                if(inARow != 0 && inARow % 2 == 1) {
                    int middle = (int) Math.ceil(j - inARow / 2.0);
                    for(int x = j - inARow; x < j; x++) {
                        noiseReducedCanny.put(i, x, new double[]{0, 0, 0});
                    }
                    noiseReducedCanny.put(i, middle, new double[]{255, 255, 255});
                } else if (inARow != 0 && inARow % 2 == 0) {
                    int middle = j - inARow / 2;
                    for(int x = j - inARow; x < j; x++) {
                        noiseReducedCanny.put(i, x, new double[]{0, 0, 0});
                    }
                    noiseReducedCanny.put(i, middle, new double[]{255, 255, 255});
                }
                inARow = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, even where the algorithm appears to work, your lines aren't 1 pixel wide. They're 3 pixels wide.

Apparently `put()` is setting 3 consecutive pixels white, starting at the given index (`middle`). The 2 unexpected pixels are causing your algorithm to "feed back" into itself, meaning they are triggering the `inARow++` line.

I'm not an OpenCV guy, and I couldn't easily find the documentation for `put()`, so I don't know how you're supposed to add a single RGB value to a `mat`. It seems likely, however, that changing this:

```
new double[]{255, 255, 255}
```

to this:

```
new double[]{255}
```

will result in the desired behavior.

You might want to fix the "blacking" lines, too.

Comment: Thank you so much! The solution worked! Just a quick question, why isn't there a bug with the new double[]{0,0,0} line? This issue only seemed to happen with the 255 number.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd recommend sitting down with a pad & paper and sketching out exactly what happens in your algorithm when those 2 extra white pixels get added to the right of the "current pixel". The bug is only triggered when an especially short "run" of white pixels, say, 1 or 2 in a row, is encountered. One of the "unintentionally added" new white pixels then triggers the bug again, b/c it creates what looks like another "short run". Black pixels can't do that.